# Python - Duplicates in dir() Is it a bug?

Tags: python, numpy

In the following sequence using numpy dir(np) returns duplicate entries.  Is this a bug?  Is dir() allowed/expected to return duplicates?

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> len(dir(np))
620
>>> np.testing
<module 'numpy.testing' from 'C:\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\testing\\__init__.py'>
>>> len(dir(np))
621
>>> [i for i in dir(np) if i == "testing"]
['testing', 'testing']
>>> np.__version__
'1.18.1'
>>>
```

Comment: This seems to be quite version-dependent; on Python 3.6.2 I only get one copy of `'testing'`, and in fact for me `len(dir(np)) == len(set(dir(np)))`. The `dir()` function is not very strictly specified in the Python docs: *"Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases."* https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: So, it's not a bug, in the sense that it doesn't violate the spec.

Comment: @kaya3: In this case, it's not even the default `dir` heuristic being used; `numpy` run on 3.7+ explicitly defines a module level `__dir__`, which overrides the default `__dir__` implementation (that `dir` is implemented in terms of).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks to be a (relatively harmless) bug triggered by an optimization `numpy` put in to avoid the expense of importing the `testing` subpackage eagerly, while still providing `testing` and `Tester` as attributes of the root `numpy` package.

The optimization uses a module-level `__getattr__` (only available on Python 3.7+, so it's not used on 3.6 and earlier) to import them only if they're explicitly accessed (at which point `testing` becomes a real attribute of `numpy`, as child modules and packages are attached to their parent as attributes on import automatically), but to continue pretending they're imported eagerly, it also defines a module-level `__dir__` that pretends they already exist:

```
def __dir__():
    return list(globals().keys()) + ['Tester', 'testing']
```

The flaw here is that, if `numpy.testing` is imported (either explicitly, or implicitly through the `__getattr__` hook), then it already appears in `globals()`, so adding `['Tester', 'testing']` to the `list` adds a second copy of `'testing'` to the result of `dir`.

They could trivially fix this by deduping (before converting to `list`, or just omitting the conversion, since [`dir` is already documented to perform the conversion automatically](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__dir__#object.__dir__)), rather than concatenating after, e.g.:

```
def __dir__():
    return globals().keys() | {'Tester', 'testing'}
```

but it's not a serious bug; code that breaks because `dir` produces a doubled result is likely pretty brittle and buggy from the get-go.

The full explanation for this optimization is in the source comments:

```
    # Importing Tester requires importing all of UnitTest which is not a
    # cheap import Since it is mainly used in test suits, we lazy import it
    # here to save on the order of 10 ms of import time for most users
    #
    # The previous way Tester was imported also had a side effect of adding
    # the full `numpy.testing` namespace
    #
    # module level getattr is only supported in 3.7 onwards
    # https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0562/
```

On 3.6 and earlier, the code path defining `__getattr__` and `__dir__` is skipped, and all it does is:

```
    # We don't actually use this ourselves anymore, but I'm not 100% sure that
    # no-one else in the world is using it (though I hope not)
    from .testing import Tester
```

which means `testing` and `Tester` are "real" attributes from the get-go, and the bug doesn't arise.